# .strings mac localization files external editor?

Tags: xcode, macos, localization, localizable.strings

I hate editing the strings files in xcode!

I tried to open the file as ASCII, it is better but you see only one line of the string.

Is there an option I missed?

And does anyone know a good editor for .strings files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Property List Editor` in `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/`

Or if you prefer text editor, get [BBEdit](http://bbedit.com/products/bbedit/) if you haven't yet. Every Mac programmer should have a copy.

Comment: Sorry for the un accept but http://crowdin.net is great.

Comment: Crowdin is way too expensive. We need better a solution.

Answer (score 2):

`.strings` files should almost always be `UTF-16`, as outlined in [Localizing String Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000005-SW1).

TextEdit should work okay as long as it's properly interpreting the .strings files as UTF-16.

Answer (score 2):

Property List Editor is no longer available by default as of OS X 10.7.  We are now expected to edit plist files using bloated XCode 4.

However, it's possible to get the old Snow Leopard version of the [Property List Editor working on Lion](http://sveinbjorn.org/install_property_list_editor_app_on_mac_os_x_lion):